# Taking user input - "jump" - in my HTML5 canvas Game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'am trying to create a basic html5 canvas game world.
I am trying to implement this in pure JavaScript before i continue to frameworks. I would like to get input via the keyboard to (1) make the character jump.
And if someones up for it help me understand/implement a side-scroller game world or at least some info on how to get started with that.

```
//capture user input
            $k(document).keydown(function(event)
            {   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                if (keycode == 87) { //w
                    me.clearCanvas();
                    me.pY = me.pY - 10;
                    //Draw Player on stage
                    me.drawPlayer(me.pX,me.pY,68);
                }
                /* if (keycode == 83) { //s
                    me.clearCanvas();
                    me.pY = me.pY + 10;
                    //Draw Player on stage
                    me.drawPlayer(me.pX,me.pY,68);
                }  */
                if (keycode == 65) { //a
                    me.clearCanvas();
                    me.pX = me.pX - 10;
                    //Draw Player on stage
                    me.drawPlayer(me.pX,me.pY,65);
                }
                if (keycode == 68) { //d
                    me.clearCanvas();
                    me.pX = me.pX + 10;
                    //Draw Player on stage
                    me.drawPlayer(me.pX,me.pY,68);
                }       
            });
```

please check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GAIsaaks/kbez4crk/1/

Thanks in advance

Comment: that jsfiddle seems pretty busted

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't seem to be working, even with including jQuery.

Comment: I have these Fiddles laying around. They are crude demos but they might be instructive (or not?). **Jumping:** https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qDQBh/, **Running:** http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qjamY/

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd only record the inputs as they come in and use the update loop to trigger the action.
i.e.:
on pressing the up arrow you'd set character.isJumping = true;
in the update loop you might check if the user is trying to jump. if the character is on the ground you start the jump, if not you reset the flag (or maybe trigger a double jump).
in each update set the height according to your jump function (first half going up, second half going down again).
if the character touches a platform/the ground you clear the jump state. if the character touches the bottom of the screen it might die.